# Errors in the use of the Devil libraries

Tags: c++, devil

I found [this tutorial](http://bobobobo.wordpress.com/2009/03/02/how-to-load-a-png-image-in-c/), but when I copy code to my C++ project, there are many errors:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in Tekstury123 ---------------

Compiling: main.cpp
C:\Users\piotrek\Documents\CodeBlocks Projects\Tekstury123\main.cpp:7: warning: ignoring #pragma comment 
Linking console executable: bin\Debug\Tekstury123.exe
obj\Debug\main.o: In function `main':
C:/Users/piotrek/Documents/CodeBlocks Projects/Tekstury123/main.cpp:20: undefined reference to `_imp__ilInit@0'
C:/Users/piotrek/Documents/CodeBlocks Projects/Tekstury123/main.cpp:24: undefined reference to `_imp__ilLoadImage@4'
C:/Users/piotrek/Documents/CodeBlocks Projects/Tekstury123/main.cpp:34: undefined reference to `_imp__ilGetError@0'
C:/Users/piotrek/Documents/CodeBlocks Projects/Tekstury123/main.cpp:36: undefined reference to `_imp__ilGetString@4'
C:/Users/piotrek/Documents/CodeBlocks Projects/Tekstury123/main.cpp:39: undefined reference to `_imp__ilGetInteger@4'
C:/Users/piotrek/Documents/CodeBlocks Projects/Tekstury123/main.cpp:41: undefined reference to `_imp__ilGetData@0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
6 errors, 1 warnings
```

How can I fix this errors? Can you help me?
I use Windows, Code::Blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler ignores `#pragma comment` directive, as it's said in the output. You have to [link against libdevil.a manually](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a3-using-libraries-with-codeblocks/).